# Is $i$ indexing the first or second dimension in $\mathbf{x}_i$, where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$?

Tags: neural-networks, math, transformer, linear-algebra, vector-space

I was reading the following notes on the math behind transformers and was confused about what $\mathbf{x}_i$ is? If $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$, then is the $i$ indexing the $n$ or the the $d$? Am I correct to conclude that it has to be $n$ since the $W$'s are in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times k}$?

https://johnthickstun.com/docs/transformers.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be correct, $d$ is the dimension of the input vectors ${\bf x}_i$, $n$ is the amount of input vectors, $i=1,...,n$, and $k,m$ is the amount of "features" or output dimension (for the current layer).

This notation is a little inconsistent, as with $X\in \Bbb R^{n\times d}$ the ${\bf x}_i\in \Bbb R^{1\times d}$ would be the rows of that matrix, so the matrix-vector products should be $W^T{\bf x}_i^T=({\bf x}_iW)^T=({\bf e}_iXW)^T$.